# Convergence test of $\sum\limits_{n=3}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n\log(n)\log(\log(n))}$

Tags: calculus, integration, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

I know, there are some threads dealing with this sum but I want to solve it with the integral test for convergence([more](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_test_for_convergence))

> $$\sum\limits_{n=3}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n\log(n)\log(\log(n))}$$

I can't find the right substitution here:
$$\int\limits_3^{\infty} \frac{1}{x\log(x)\log(\log(x))}dx$$ I used $t=\log(x)$ but it doesn't work. Any hints?

Comment: @SameerKailasa one log too many there

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint**. One has, for $x\ge3$,
$$
(\log(\log x))'=\frac{\frac1x}{\log x}=\frac1{x\log x}
$$ giving
$$
\int\limits_3^{\infty} \frac{1}{x\log(x)\log(\log x)}dx=\int\limits_3^{\infty} \frac{\frac1{x\log x}}{\log(\log x)}dx=\int\limits_3^{\infty} \frac{(\log(\log x))'}{\log(\log x)}dx.
$$

Answer (score 2):

Make the substitution $t = \ln(n)$.  We find that
$$
\int\limits_3^{\infty} \frac{1}{n\log(n)\log(\log(n))} = 
\int_3^\infty \frac{1}{t(n)\ln(t(n))} \frac{1}n dn = \\
\int_{\ln 3}^\infty \frac{1}{t\ln(t)}\,dt
$$
Integrate this using the further substitution $u = \ln(t)$.

Alternatively, start with the substitution $t = \ln(\ln(n))$.

Answer (score 0):

Just apply [Cauchy's condensation test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_condensation_test) twice to get that the series is divergent.

As an alternative, the substitution $x=\exp(\exp t)$ gives:
$$ \int_{e^e}^{\exp(e^M)}\frac{dx}{x\log(x)\log\log(x)} = \log M,$$

hence $\sum_{n=3}^{N}\frac{1}{n\log(n)\log\log(n)}$ diverges like $\log\log\log N$, i.e. extremely slow, but still.

Answer (score -1):

Taking log(logx) = t we get [log∞ - log 3 ] =∞

So , series is divergent .

And if we have power over (log(log x))^a then it is convergent if a>1 by Integral test .

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).